# How to make Angular ui grid expand all rows initially?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui grid to show a list of data and I am trying to initially expand all rows.

I am trying to do this in the onRegisterApi event:

```
scope.GridOptions =
        {
            data: properties,
            columnDefs: 
            [
                { name: "Full Address", field: "FullAddress" },
                { name: "Suburb", field: "Suburb" },
                { name: "Property Type", field: "PropertyType" },
                { name: "Price", field: "Price", cellFilter: 'currency'},
                { name: "Status", field: "Status" },
                { name: "Sale Type", field: "SaleType" }, 
                { name: "Date Created", field: "CreateDate", cellFilter: "date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mma'"}
            ],
            expandableRowTemplate: 'template.html',
            expandableRowHeight: 200,
            onRegisterApi: (gridApi) => 
            {
                scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged(scope,(row) =>
                {
                    if (row.isExpanded) {
                        this.scope.GridOptions.expandableRowScope = row.entity;
                    }
                });
                gridApi.expandable.expandAllRows();

            }
        };
```

But the code above does not work. It looks like when I call expandAllRows() the rows are not rendered yet.

Comment: BTW: I use typescript but it has little difference with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find I can expand all rows by using rowsRendered event:

```
gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered(scope,() => {
        if (!gridApi.grid.expandable.expandedAll && !initialized)
        {
            gridApi.expandable.expandAllRows();
            initialized = true;
         }
});
```

I have used a variable initialized to identify if this is the first time rows are rendered as I only want to expand all rows initially.

Comment: Could you provide a working example of your solution? Either I am doing something wrong in going from TypeScript to JavaScript or this does not work for me using v3.0.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the following worked:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      ...
      onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        $scope.gridApi.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function() {
          $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
        });
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me for all of my grid use cases.

```
        $scope.gridApi.grid.registerDataChangeCallback(function() {
            if($scope.gridApi.grid.treeBase.tree instanceof Array){
                $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
            }

        });
```

The following works in every case I have tested. DataChangeCallback is called twice (for some unknown reason) on initial page load. The first time, gridApi.grid.treeBase.tree is an object which causes the issue with gridApi.grid.treeBase.tree.forEach above:

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me, the following did:

```
scope.gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered(null, () => {
    scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, but no guarantee that it won't break anything... (looks good in my tests):

You need to change the source code, for example in ui-grid.js, i.e. the one your are deploying with your app:

1. In the addOrUseNode: function(...) inside the createTree: function(...) simply change COLLAPSED to EXPANDED for newNodes:

addOrUseNode: function (grid, row, parents, aggregationBase) {
...
var newNode = { state: uiGridTreeBaseConstants.EXPANDED, row: row, parentRow: null, aggregations: newAggregations, children: [] };
...
}

2. In module.service('uiGridTreeBaseService'... initializeGrid: function(grid) set grid.treeBase.expandAll from false to true (to let the tree know that all rows are expanded on initialitation)
3. [looks this is optional for the treeView]: Do the same In module.service('uiGridExpandableService', ['gridUtil', function (gridUtil) {...} in initializeGrid: function (grid). Change grid.expandable.expandedAll from false to true