# Expand the grouping automatically in begin in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angular-ui-grid

I have followed the steps in th [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping) to construct my grouping.

What i want to have is expanding certain (or all) rows in begin automatically. In tutorial they used: `$scope.gridApi.treeBase.toggleRowTreeState($scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[rowNum]);`
and: $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();

They are working after my grid is ready but; my grid is not initialized in begin in my app and just after some required actions the grid will be shown and initialized. Therefore, i don't know how to use them to expand the rows automatically.

Thus i believe i need some callback like onReady. Any idea?

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893210/how-to-make-angular-ui-grid-expand-all-rows-initially

Comment: the most rated answer worked just for the initializing. the other one did not work

Answer (score 0):

i personally used the ui-grid in my angularjs projects. simply using `enableGrouping: true` in grid_options worked fine. i.e initially rows expanded automatically.

Comment: which version is it? i'm using 3.0.6 and it is not working... and i don't see any relation enabling grouping and auto expanding